# REGEX Sqlite case-insensitive not working

Tags: regex, sqlite, case-insensitive

I can't get case insensitive searches to work for REGEX in SQLITE. Is the syntax supported?

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name REGEXP 'smith[s]*\i'
```

I would expect the following answers (assuming the database has these entries):

Smith
Smiths
smith
smitH <--- Not a typo but in database

Note - This is a small part of a larger REGEX, so I won't be using LIKE

Comment: Which `REGEXP` implementation are you using? [ICU](http://www.sqlite.org/src/artifact/bf8461d8cdc6b8f514c080e4e10dc3b2bbdfefa9)?

Comment: The REGEXP implementation I am using came built into the SQLite Manager in Firefox when I selected the option for user defined functions. Since I did not download ICU I'm going to assume I'm not using that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `REGEXP` function shipped with SQLite Manager is implented in JavaScript as follows:

```js
var regExp = new RegExp(aValues.getString(0));
var strVal = new String(aValues.getString(1));

if (strVal.match(regExp)) return 1;
else return 0;
```

To get case-insensitive searches with the [JavaScript RegExp object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp), you would not add a flag to the pattern string itself, but pass the `i` flag in the second parameter to the `RegExp` constructor. However, the binary `REGEXP` operator does not have a third flags parameter, and the code does not try to extract flags from the pattern, so these flags are not supported in this implementation.

Answer (score 3):

As described by CL, this feature is not supported in SQLite. A simple solution to this problem is to "lowercase" the left-hand side of the REGEXP expression using lower:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE lower(name) REGEXP 'smith[s]*';
```

it is not ideal, but it works. But pay attention to diacritics. I would read the documentation for lower if your text uses them.

Answer (score 0):

From https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html

If an application-defined SQL function named "regexp" is added at run-time, then the "X REGEXP Y" operator will be implemented as a call to "regexp(Y,X)".